# ruby memoization, efficiency

Tags: ruby, memoization

This question is mostly about Ruby internals, the speed can be gauged with a simple benchmark.

**What's the most efficient way to memoize a return value in ruby?**

I've always memoized values with:

```
def method
  @value ||= calculate_value
end
```

But since it technically expands to:

```
@value = @value || calculate_value
```

I wonder about the efficiency of re-executing the same assignment each time.

Would this be better?

```
def method
  @value ? @value : (@value = calculate_value)
end
```

Also, does it change in different interpreters? MRI, Rubinius, etc.

Comment: If calculate_value is expensive and it can return false or nil, you must think in something like `defined? @value ? @value : (@value = calculate_value)`.

Comment: An interesting question, one whose answer I am glad to know. Don't forget to select an answer, if any were helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example

```
@value ||= calculate_value
```

is equivalent to

```
@value || @value = calculate_value
```

and is **not** equivalent to

```
@value = @value || calculate_value
```

Therefore the answer is: It is very efficient. It is not re-assigned each time.

Comment: can you prove it somehow? E.g. ruby source code quotes or anything? Simple benchmark shows that (value ||= calculate_value) works 30% slower than (value || value = calculate_value).

Comment: Sure you may want to read this article by Peter Cooper (http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) or some threads in the Rubyforum (https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/151660/)

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. `a += 1` is equivalent to `a = a + 1`. The same rule applies to other operators: `a ||= 1` is expanded to `a = a || 1`.

Comment: @tompave: *Do not confuse [op]= with anything related to ||= or &&=. They're entirely different ideas and are implemented entirely different[ly].* (also see: http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html

Comment: ok, I just read the article you linked. It clashes with the contents of [The Ruby Programming Language](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do)

Comment: @tompave, the Debating Society awards zero points for assertions (unless you are Matz or one of a handful of others). spickerman, this applies to your answer as well, but your comments back it up.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, point taken. Just double checked the book (_The Ruby Programming Language_, Davis Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto, 2008) covers MRI 1.8 and 1.9, and at page 96 discusses the `||=` operator specifically. It clearly states that it's expanded like the others.

Comment: @tompave, note the last paragraph in the box "The ||= Idiom", on p. 97: "The abbreviated assignment operator ||= behaves slightly differently than the expansion shown here. If the lvalue of ||= is not nil or false, no assignment is actually performed.  If the lvalue is an attribute or array element, the setter method that performs assignment is not invoked."

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right. I completely missed the second part of the box on page 97.

Answer (score 0):

@spickermann, @tompave, sorry for posting it as an answer but I need code formatting to post benchmark results for different usecases. It looks like explicit way is the fastest `@a || @a = calculated_value`

```
> n = 10000000;
> a = 1;
> puts Benchmark.measure { n.times { a ||= 1 } }
  0.570000   0.000000   0.570000 (  0.569977)
> puts Benchmark.measure { n.times { a ? a : a = 1 } }
  0.560000   0.000000   0.560000 (  0.562855)
> puts Benchmark.measure { n.times { a || a = 1 } }
  0.530000   0.000000   0.530000 (  0.532715)
> @a = 1;
> puts Benchmark.measure { n.times { @a ||= 1 } }
  0.870000   0.000000   0.870000 (  0.869489)
> puts Benchmark.measure { n.times { @a ? @a : @a = 1 } }
  0.670000   0.000000   0.670000 (  0.668910)
> puts Benchmark.measure { n.times { @a || @a = 1 } }
  0.610000   0.000000   0.610000 (  0.613978)
```

ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

All 3 notations behave the same from result point of view, however last one is the fasted one from performance point of view. Unfortunately it is all empirical and I can't link any ruby source code here.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not accurate. You are only considering one case of the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think any differences between `||=` and `... = ... || ...` should be subtle.

Perhaps, a much more efficient way is to switch the method when the value is set. This switching happens only once, and from there on, the method call becomes just a reference to the variable, so it should be fast, and the advantage increases as the number of times the method is called increases.

```
def method
  alias method memoized_value
  @value ||= calculate_value
end

def memoized_value; @value end
```

This assumes that `calculate_value` always returns a truthy value, and there is no other part in the code that modifies the value so that once `method` is called, the variable's value remains truthy.

Comment: interesting, but for instance methods `alias` would be called at least once for each instance, and IIRC it blows away Ruby's method cache.

Comment: @tompave I intended the two methods to be pairs. You need these pairs as many variables you want to do memoization.

Comment: yes, but it will wipe the method cache each time an `alias` is created.